# How to store data crawled in scrapy in specfic order?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, web-crawler

I have to crawl data from a web page in a specfic order as liked i declared fields in my item class and then have to put them in csv file.problem now occuring is there its stores data not in specfic order as like its scrapping data of any field and putting in csv file but i want it should store data as i declared in my item class. I am newbie in python. can you tell me how to do this

For ex:
my item class is 
class DmozItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    link = Field()
    desc = Field()

Now when its storing data in csv file its storing first desc ,link and then title 
"desc": [], "link": ["/Computers/Programming/"], "title": ["Programming"]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the order of data in csv file is not  what you declared is because item is a dict data type. The order of keys in dict is decided by their alphabet order. The logic of export items to csv file is implemented in

> scrapy\contrib\exporter__init__.py

You can rewrite the _get_serialized_fields method of BaseItemExporter to let it yield key-value pair in the order of your declaration. Here is an example code

```
field_iter = ['title', 'link', 'desc']
for field_name in field_iter:
    if field_name in item:
        field = item.fields[field_name]
        value = self.serialize_field(field, field_name, item[field_name])
    else:
        value = default_value
    yield field_name, value
```

But do remember, it is not an universal solution.

Comment: Hey are you suggesting to add one line "field_iter = ['title', 'link', 'desc'] " because all other code is same but even after adding this output is coming same

Comment: Also i have searched in docs i found this:fields_to_export
A list with the name of the fields that will be exported, or None if you want to export all fields. Defaults to None.

Some exporters (like CsvItemExporter) respect the order of the fields defined in this attribute.  but not able to find this in BaseItemExporter

Comment: yes after adding iter list its working fine for csv files so thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this we have to make a list in fields_to_export in the BaseItemExporter class 
field_iter = ['Offer', 'SKU', 'VendorCode'] like this
and then have to pass this list in the field